# Echo image url from Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, image, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to return the url of an image that was uploaded to a post of a certain taxonomy (created by the IssueM plugin), using Advance Custom Fields plugin for WP. I set the rule to 'show this field group if the Taxonomy Term is equal to Issues'. The code I am using is thus:

```
    <div class="article-cover clearfix" style="background:url('<?php 
$image = get_field('toc_img');
echo $image['url']; ?>') center center;background-size:cover;">
</div>
```

I want it to return the URL, which is something like

http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2014/image.jpg

Instead it returns something that looks like the area the image was uploaded in, which is

http://www.mysite/the-itinerant/articles/?issue=the-itinerant-01

The Advance Custom Fields image upload is designed to upload an image to a specific 'issue', which is a custom taxonomy created by the IssueM plugin. I have successfully uploaded the image to Issue 01, which this URL suggests. I just can't return the correct path.

Ultimately this bit of code should return the relevant image to the relevant issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can'y you just simply call the ACF for the image as such:

```
<?php the_field('toc-img'); ?>
```

That would give you the url of the image

Comment: I tried that. I'm wondering if there is something I have to call first to tell WP that the image is specific to the issue.

Comment: Have you configured the ACF correctly? If you have you should be able to call the function "the_field(' ');"

Comment: I assume so. I've set the Return Value to Image Object (though I have tried URL and ID) and Conditional Logic to No.

Comment: I still think there might be a config error. Could you please post a screenshot over your configs?

Comment: Stoggy, see here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25233603/screen.png and here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25233603/screen2.png

Comment: Try to use the img url and call it with <?php the_field("toc_image"); ?> also try change the inage size to full. Are the location rules true? Is that where you want to print the image? Notice how you in your above code used ("toc_img"); in stead of ("toc_image");

Comment: I have tried to create a new image field, tried to output url and I even tried a basic text field. All the fields appeared in the Issue edit page and were saved to the database, but they are not appearing on the page template.

Comment: Feels like the location rules needs to be changed to match the page where you want to print your image

Comment: No, not yet. I've been in touch with ACF and we agreed this has something to do with taxonomies and the need to call taxonomy/post ID before the image. All testing so far was done on my local machine but over the next couple of days I'm going to try this on a live site. I'll keep you posted, and thanks for the help so far...

Comment: I'm having the same problem but with Articles, did you manage to solve it?